# flask-restful having a get/<id> and post with json in the same class

Tags: python, json, routes, flask, multimethod

The get method on user works if the # api.add_resource(User, '/user/')
line is uncommented, and the other api.add_resource is. 
The inverse of that is true to make the post method work.

How can I get both of these paths to work?

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.ext.restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
import os
# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class User(Resource):

    def get(self, userid):
        print type(userid)
        if(userid == '1'):
            return {'id':1, 'name':'foo'}
        else:
            abort(404, message="user not found")

    def post(self):
        # should just return the json that was posted to it
        return request.get_json(force=True)

api.add_resource(User, '/user/')
# api.add_resource(User, '/user/<string:userid>')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flask-Restful [supports registering multiple URLs for a single resource](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.Api.add_resource).  Simply provide both URLs when you register the `User` resource:

```
api.add_resource(User, '/user/', '/user/<userid>')
```

Comment: What might be missing here is how "/" and "/id" are both supported in the python code. Would there be 2 functions with the same name? Would there be one function and the programmer would check the "id" against None?

Comment: In this framework, you'd check against `user_id is None` to distinguish the cases.

Comment: It may be a better convention to just make a new flask_restful class to represent the id routes... this is far more organized than using a conditional in every single restful function IMO...