# `fields.Url('some_resource')` doesn't append the `id` at the end if using blueprints

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am using blueprints and I have this line to create the blueprint:

`api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)`

And `some_resources` is added and blueprint is registered by below lines:

```
rest_api = Api()
rest_api.init_app(api_bp)
rest_api.add_resource(SomeResourceApi, '/some_resources', '/some_resources/<int:some_resource_id>', endpoint='some_resources')
app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/some/api/v1.0')
```

The fields dict used for `marshal()` has `'uri': fields.Url('api.some_resources'),`
The output that I receive is `"uri": "/some/api/v1.0/some_resources"` inside my response. *Notice that the id is not appended at the end in the url.*

Just to be sure I replaced the line `'uri': fields.Url('api.some_resources'),` inside my field dict to `'id': fields.Integer` and in this case the integer id is returned correctly inside the response.

Also I have tested both with the decorator `@marshal_with` and the method `marshal()`, that doesn't make any difference.

For now, I am getting my work done by having my fields dict to have an extra field: `id` with the value `fields.Integer` which contains the actual id, so the output has these two fields in response which collectively gives the complete address:

```
"uri": "/some/api/v1.0/some_resources",
"id": 11
```

While this serves the purpose, it looks kind of hacky.

Am I doing anything wrong that the ids are not appended in the response when using `fields.Url()`?

**Library Version details:**

Flask==1.0.2

Flask-RESTful==0.3.6

Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2

SQLAlchemy==1.2.10

Corresponding github issue: https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should route the request for a list of items (`/some_resources`) and the detail for single items (`/some_resources/:id`) through the same resource class.

`fields.Url` is just calling [flask's `url_for()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.url_for) under the hood and is probably just using the first matching resource path that it finds. Maybe if you swapped the order of the paths passed to `add_resource` it would work.

Comment: okay, I think I misused the support for multiple urls. Got the motivation from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771259/1781024
where was able to identify whether the request is for single or multiple resource inside a single method based on the `None` check for the `id`.

Will try with multiple resource classes for list and single resource. Thanks

Comment: well, having separate resource classes for single and list items did solve the issue, but at the cost of naming my path param as `<int:id>`, not as `<int:some_resource_id>` and thus making the same change in the corresponding `get` method i.e. `get(self, id)` instead of `get(self, some_resource_id)`.

If I name it as anything but `id`, I receive the error: _Could not build url for endpoint 'api.some_resource' with values [<field names here>]. Did you forget to specify values ['some_resource_id']?_

Do I need to do something else, so that I can name my variable different than `id`?

Comment: That's expected, your object has an `id` property and does not have an `some_resource_id` property. The names of the URL parameters in the route have to correspond with a model property for `fields.Url` to figure out the proper URL.